# How to convert scheme://filename.pdf to relative path in Drupal 7?

Tags: file, api, drupal-7

Is there a function in Drupal 7 to that converts "public://filename.pdf" to "/path_to_public_directory/filename.pdf"? I found function that put together a scheme path but can't find one that does the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`file_create_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) to do exactly that:

```
$uri = 'public://filename.pdf';
$path = file_create_url($uri);
```

Comment: This returns an absolute path, not a relative path... Any way of getting a relative path?

Comment: You can use global $base_url; then str_replace($base_url, '', file_create_url($uri]));

Answer (score 0):

Use conf_path() to find the path to your files directory.

```
<?php
    $drupal_files = conf_path() . "/files";
    print "The Files Directory: " . $drupal_files;
?>
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/conf_path

Answer (score 0):

drupal_realpath($uri)
Resolves the absolute filepath of a local URI or filepath.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7

Comment: This resolves to the absolute path from the file system root - not to the relative path as requested.